# How to get a list of all the headers for logging in web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, http-headers, asp.net-web-api2, request-headers

I want to log all the request headers. I already have a filter like so.
Now how do I get all the request header so that I can log them?

```
public class LogApiFilter : AbstractActionFilter
{
    private readonly ILog m_Log;

    public override bool AllowMultiple
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public LogApiFilter(ILog iLog)
    {
        if (iLog == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("log instance injected is null.");
        m_Log = iLog;

    }
    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext context)
    {
        m_Log.Debug("Web api Controller Name and Action method Name: " 
            + context.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName 
            + ", " + context.ActionDescriptor.ActionName);
        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, for my own records and for others, I have comeup with this. Please do suggest if there is a better way.

```
    private string GetRequestHeaders(HttpActionContext context)
    {
        // Note you can replace the type names sucha as string, HttpRequestHeaders, List<KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>>>
        // with var keyword where ever possible for readability.
        string headerString = string.Empty;
        HttpRequestHeaders requestHeaders = context.Request.Headers;
        List<KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>>> headerList = requestHeaders.ToList();
        foreach (var header in headerList)
        {
            string key = header.Key;
            List<string> valueList = header.Value.ToList();
            string valueString = string.Empty;
            foreach (var v in valueList)
            {
                valueString = valueString + v + "-";
            }
            headerString = headerString + key + ": " + valueString + Environment.NewLine;
        }

        return headerString;
    }
```

The above method can be called from the action filter in the question. I am calling it from the method, OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext context).

I am using ninject for di, so this is how I have configured it.

```
kernel.BindHttpFilter<LogApiFilter>(System.Web.Http.Filters.FilterScope.Global);
kernel.BindHttpFilter<ApiExceptionFilterAttribute>(System.Web.Http.Filters.FilterScope.Global);
kernel.BindFilter<LogMvcFilter>(System.Web.Mvc.FilterScope.Global, 0);
```

Comment: I would just serialise the whole headers object to JSON, using whatever JSON serialiser i have handy, saves you writing all that string handling and can be auto formatted etc